# Add "?XDEBUG_PROFILE=on" at the end of each URL using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, drupal-7, redirect

I am using `X-debug` for memory profiling of my `Drupal` project and I am getting the logs and able to read them using `Kcachegrind`. I am getting different cachegrind files whenever I add **?XDEBUG_PROFILE=on** at the end of the url. So it is pretty helpful to identify the memory usages.

But now I have to give **?XDEBUG_PROFILE=on** manually to the end of desired URLs. Is there any way to add **?XDEBUG_PROFILE=on** at the end of each URL with help of `.htaccess` or some other way?

So if my url is `http://localhsot/mysite/home`, then the new one will be `http://localhsot/mysite/home?XDEBUG_PROFILE=on` and if the url is `http://localhsot/mysite/settings` then the new URL will be `http://localhsot/mysite/settings?XDEBUG_PROFILE=on`

Please help on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Hope this will help you.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(?!XDEBUG_PROFILE)
RewriteRule (.*) /mysite/$1?XDEBUG_PROFILE=on [L,R,QSA]
```

Add the above lines in your Drupal .htaccess

Comment: Always Welcome :)